# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'NSJSONReadingOptions'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting a weird compiler warning. It says:

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 
'NSJSONReadingOptions' (aka 'enum NSJSONReadingOptions')
```

Here is the block that its in:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    //Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 
    'NSJSONReadingOptions' (aka 'enum NSJSONReadingOptions')

    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing weird about the compiler warning. Just read it carefully. It tells you _exactly_ what is wrong with your code. You'll find it a lot easier to fix your problems if you don't start thinking "this compiler warning is weird", but "There's a problem with my code. What is the problem? "

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just replace `options:nil` by `options:0`.

`nil` is ultimately defined as `((void*)0)` and has *pointer type*, but `NSJSONReadingOptions` (as an enum) is a *integer type*.